# Posting the link address after the link using jQuery (on screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need the ability to place a link address after the link itself in a table full of reference links for staff. I've done this easily with CSS before, but the address is read-only: the user cannot copy and paste it into a document. Instead, I'd like to do it with a jQuery append after the  element, with a presentation like the CSS method. So far, I've been unsuccessful. Can someone provide guidance?

```html
<tr><td><a href="http://test.com/documents/doctorateofeducation.pdf"><strong>Review of Doctor of Education (EdD) Programs</strong></a></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.append()` on each anchor, appending its link URL. You can wrap it in a span with a class for styling purposes.

```
$("a").append(function() {
    return $("span", {
        text: this.href,
        "class": "anchorlink"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the append wouldn't work, but I was successful with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#policies_div a').each(function(){
     var address = this.href;
     this.innerHTML += ' <span class="linktoshare">' + address; + '</span>';
});
});

</script>
```

Thanks for your help - it steered me in the right direction.